# Python 3 - First time coding need help - Counting the highest occurring string in an array

Tags: python, arrays, frequency

Big noob here just starting coding. So in Python 3, say you are given an array consisting of names like [Bob, Bob, Ben, Alex, Bob]. I want it to return the number '3', as 'Bob' occurs the most, with three occurrences. This can be for any given array of names. Thanks

seen examples such as this but not exactly what im looking for

```
from collections import Counter
list1=['apple','egg','apple','banana','egg','apple']
counts = Counter(list1)
print(counts)
# Counter({'apple': 3, 'egg': 2, 'banana': 1})
```

Comment: Have you read the documentation for `Counter`? It's very easy the get the count of the `most_common` item...

Answer (score 0):

You can just use the `max`function with the dict values.

Like this:

```
from collections import Counter
list1=['apple','egg','apple','banana','egg','apple']
counts = Counter(list1)
print(max(counts.values()))
```

Comment: If you think this is the solution to your question, please mark it as the best answer. Thanks!